# How can I retrieve the home directory/profile path of a different local user with Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, adsi, home-directory

Rather than looking for "$env:HOMEDIR", I'm looking for a way to query the home directory of a different user account. The powershell equivalent of "~bob".

I attempted using [ADSI]:

```
# After creating a local account called 'other.user'
PS> $user = [ADSI]'WinNT://localhost/other.user,user'
PS> $user.name
other.user
PS> $user.HomeDirectory

PS>
```

even when executed from the Administrator account in an elevated powershell.

For sanity, I tried doing the same check on the existing user:

```
PS> $user = [ADSI]('WinNT://localhost/{0},user' -f [Environment]::UserName)
PS> $user.name
this.user    # paraphrase
PS> $user.HomeDirectory

PS> $user.properties.HomeDirectory

PS>
```

Comment: Windows is different. It doesn't have just one home directory. It does have a profile folder, but everything that matters that you would normally think of within that folder can also be configured in a completely different location. Especially in enterprise environment this is common: the profile folder might be untouched from the default, but the Documents and Desktop folders could be mapped to a network share to follow the user to different workstations, and the Downloads folder might be mapped elsewhere on the disk to save backup space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [`Get-CimInstance`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) with  [`Get-LocalUser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser):

```
$userName = 'other.user'
(
  Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID = '$((Get-LocalUser $userName).Sid)'"
).LocalPath
```

This outputs the path of the targeted user's ***profile* directory**, such as `C:\Users\other.user`.

**Note**: The *profile* directory is *typically*, but **not necessarily the same as a user's *home* directory** - the latter can be configured to point elsewhere, such as to a network share, and is reflected in a *pair* of environment variables for the current user, `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`.

---

To get the **true *home* directory**:

- If the targeted user is stored in **Active Directory**, the following *may* work (untested):

  ```
  $userName = 'other.user'
  $user = Get-ADUser $userName -Property HomeDrive, HomeDirectory
  '{0}{1}' -f $user.HomeDrive, $user.HomeDirectory
  ```
- For a **local-only user**:

  - I'm personally not aware of a method, given that the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` environment variables are *dynamically* added to the registry, *when that user logs on to a window station (creates an OS session)*, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment`. By contrast, if you load another user's profile file (the hidden `NTUSER.DAT` file located in the user's profile directory) into the registry on demand, such as via `reg.exe load` or via the [`CreateProcessWithLogon()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) WinAPI function (as also used by `runas.exe`<sup>[1]</sup>), these values are *not* added.
  - If someone knows if and where the home-directory information is contained in the *non-volatile* information of a user's profile (as accessible via the registry after loading it), do let us know.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The relevant properties of the [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) (whose type accelerator is `[adsi]`) instance *should* be `.Profile` and `.HomeDirDrive` / `.HomeDirectory`, but at least on my Windows 10 machine they *aren't populated*; e.g.:

```
PS> ([adsi] 'WinNT://localhost/jdoe,user') | Format-List *

# ...
HomeDirectory              : {}
# ...
Profile                    : {}
HomeDirDrive               : {}
# ...
```

---

<sup>[1] Beware that something like `runas.exe /profile /user:$userName cmd /c echo %HOMEDRIVE%HOMEPATH%` in effect reports `%HOMEDRIVE%` as `C:` and `%HOMEPATH%` as `\Windows\System32`(!), based on the behavior of `CreateProcessWithLogon()`, which - strangely - sets these variables to the *working directory* of the launched process, which defaults to `C:\Windows\System32`.</sup>

Comment: Empty properties: That's also what I was finding, I didn't think to check whether they're only populated thru AD or anything.

Comment: @kfsone, do you have access to AD? I've added information about trying to find the true _home_ directory, which may differ from the _profile_ directory via `Get-ADUser`, but I can't test it myself. Without AD, things get tricky, though perhaps I'm missing something - please see my update.

Comment: Not at the point that I need to know where their homedir is. We were trying to crack a chicken-and-egg problem bootstrapping remote employee-owned devices.

Answer (score 2):

The other alternative to complement [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281884/15339544) can be to query the registry directly, this combines [`Get-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) with [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
$sid = (Get-LocalUser other.user).Sid
Get-ItemPropertyValue "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$sid" -Name ProfileImagePath
```